# How to call a vue component method from another js file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue v2.3.4 (quasar-framework v0.14.2) modal ComponentA working when clicking on a button in the same component. The MyModal component seems to work fine (as I can trigger it with a button). However I have code in a separate util.js file which should trigger the modal (from a 'myUtilElement'). How can I do that?

ComponentA.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id='lotsofstuff'></div>
    <myModal ref="myModal"></myModal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyModal from '../MyModal.vue'

export default {
  name: 'componentA',
  components: {MyModal},
  methods: {
    openModal: function () {
      this.$refs.myModal.open()
    },
    otherMethods:...etc.
}
```

Util.js

```
import ComponentA from '../ComponentA.vue'

myUtilElement.addEventListener('click', triggerModal, false)

function triggerModal () {
  ComponentA.methods.openModal()
}
```

I now get following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openModal' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.triggerModal
```

Comment: new ComponentA?

Comment: See [Non Parent-Child Communication on the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication).

Comment: It seems that you are using `this.$refs.myModal` while you named your reference `modalTest` in `<myModal ref="modalTest"></myModal>`.

Comment: @Vincent Mmh, yes, you're right! This was an presentation error (I made some adaptions before presenting, but forgot to change this ref...). I corrected it now in the question. Problem persists. I think the eventbus that Nit suggests is the way to go.

Comment: I think so, event bus is a solution.

Comment: @Nit If you make an answer out of your comment I am willing to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [non parent-child communication on the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication). Essentially, you have two common options: an event bus or centralized state management.
An event bus is a simple pub-sub pattern:

```
var bus = new Vue()
// in component A's method
bus.$emit('openModal', params)
// in component B's created hook
bus.$on('openModal', function(params) {
  // ...
})
```

The most common centralized state management library for Vue is [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html), which is analogous to Flux/Redux/etc.

[image: Sample image of Vuex data flow]

Answer (score 1):

src/eventBus.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
export default new Vue();
```

src/components/ComponentA.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="lotsofstuff">
      <!-- some code here -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="openModal">Open Modal</button>
    </div>
    <myModal></myModal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyModal from './MyModal.vue';
import EventBus from '../eventBus';

export default {
  name: 'componentA',

  components: {
    MyModal
  },

  methods: {
    openModal: function () {
      var params = {title: 'My Modal Title'}
      EventBus.$emit('OPEN_MODAL', params)
    },
    // otherMethods:...etc.
}
</script>
```

src/components/MyModal.vue

```html
<template>
  <div v-show="show">
    <div class="modal-title">{{ title }}</div>
    <!-- some code here -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus from '../eventBus';

export default {
  name: 'MyModal',

  data () {
    return {
      show: false,
      title: 'Default Title'
    }
  },

  created () {
    var self = this;

    EventBus.$on('OPEN_MODAL', function (params) {
      self.show = true;
      self.title = params.title;
    });
  },

  methods: {
    open () {
      this.show = true;
    },

    close () {
      this.show = false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```